# Flutter WEb: NoSuchMetodError: tried to call a nun-function:such as null; easyweb.dev

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-packages

I am struggling here with implementing easyweb package of flutter in web version
so basically I have downloaded and added the dependencies and I created specific class only related to easy web My widget of easy web look like this. And my goal was to make external website appear on the Main page of the website when user will click home tab.

```
import 'package:easy_web_view/easy_web_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen();
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String src = 'https://flutter.dev/';
  bool _isHtml = false;
  bool _isMarkdown = false;
  bool _useWidgets = false;
  bool _editing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
        height: 120.0, //450
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(_editing ? Icons.close : Icons.settings),
        onPressed: () {
          if (mounted)
            setState(() {
              _editing = !_editing;
            });
        },
      ),

      SizedBox(
        height: 5.0,
      ),
        Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*1.90,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.40,
        child: Card(
        elevation: 5.0,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        //shadowColor: Color(0xFF032539),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: _editing
        ? SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        SwitchListTile(
        title: Text('Html Content'),
        value: _isHtml,
        onChanged: (val) {
        if (mounted)
        setState(() {
        _isHtml = val;
        if (val) {
        _isMarkdown = false;
        src = htmlContent;
        } else {
        src = url;
        }
        });
        },
        ),
        SwitchListTile(
        title: Text('Markdown Content'),
        value: _isMarkdown,
        onChanged: (val) {
        if (mounted)
        setState(() {
        _isMarkdown = val;
        if (val) {
        _isHtml = false;
        src = markdownContent;
        } else {
        src = url;
        }
        });
        },
        ),
        SwitchListTile(
        title: Text('Use Widgets'),
        value: _useWidgets,
        onChanged: (val) {
        if (mounted)
        setState(() {
        _useWidgets = val;
        });
        },
        ),
        ],
        ),
        )
            : EasyWebView(
        src: src,
        isHtml: _isHtml,
        isMarkdown: _isMarkdown,
        convertToWidgets: _useWidgets,
        //width: 100,
        //height: 100,
        ),
        ),
        ),
        ],
      );





  }

  String get htmlContent => """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
""";

  String get markdownContent => """
# This is a heading

## Here's a smaller heading

This is a paragraph

* Here's a bulleted list
* Another item

1. And an ordered list
1. The numbers don't matter

> This is a qoute

[This is a link to Flutter](https://flutter.dev)
""";

  String get embeedHtml => """
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://flutter.dev" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
""";

  String get url => 'https://flutter.dev';
}
```

[So basically here in home tab when user click I would like to show the content of the external website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkkoU.jpg)

but it is giving me eror like this [NoSuchMetodError: tried to call  a nun-function:such as null 'this.widget.onLoaded':](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJmWr.png)

Does anyone know where I am making mistake? I am new in flutter and thats why I couldnt figure out where I am making mistake

I run the code with debug mode and it gave me following details of the bug

[Here it is saying that the bug was caused by Card widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP7EF.png)

[And here it is saying that the parameter "onLoaded" is required as you can see in the very down in Dart analysis section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prIfv.png)

As I mentioned I am new to flutter Idont know whaere to put that onladed method

If someone knows it would be really great if you can tell me

Thank you for your help
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run this with debug mode? Because sometimes i can understand why i am having an error by running it with debug mode rather than using "flutter run" in terminal.